# error in sql query : multiple values are not allowed

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables in the database

- standard
- teacher
- course

I want to `retrieve all the courses` from the `course` table which are associated with a `specific standard`.

Note that :

1. there is `1 to many relationship` between `standard` and `teacher`.
2. there is `1 to many relationship` between `teacher` and `course`.
3. there is `no direct relationship` between `standard` and `course`.

I have tried to get it but not able to retrieve the data as the no of teachers I am getting is multiple and SQL says that `multiple values are not allowed`. Is there a way?

Here is my query:

```
select CourseName
from Course
where Course.TeacherID = (
  select TeacherID
  from Teacher
  where StandardID = 7
)
```

Comment: How many rows the following SQL returns ? select TeacherID from Teacher where StandardID = 7

Comment: So this is normal... you can't affect two values to a variable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `Course.TeacherID IN` ...

Is this a school work?

Comment: no this is not a school work but i am just trying to learn vb.net with sql server 2008

Comment: It sounded just like an homework :D No problem. maybe you can vote the correct answer.

Then there is JOIN METHOD which I think is better than double SELECT.

SELECT coursename From course c INNER JOIN techers t ON c.teacherID = t.id INNER JOIN standards s ON t.standardsID = s.id WHERE standardID = 7

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I know a very little about JOINS.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you are using "=", try changing the "=" to an "IN" please. See below:

```
select CourseName
from Course
where Course.TeacherID IN (
  select TeacherID
  from Teacher
  where StandardID = 7
)
```